# Why if has a invalid field, need valid form 2 time for valid next field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, submit

I have set custom validation for my form validation, but if has a invalid field, I need put values and valid it 2 times, only in second time, it will valid next field, what is problem?

[View in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lai32290/qX9du/)

My form:

```
<form>
    <label>Login:</label>
    <input type="text" name="login" id="login" required/><br/>
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" required/><br/>
    <label>Password Confirm:</label>
    <input type="password" name="pass_conf" id="pass_conf" required/><br/>

    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

My Javascript:

```
// This code is loaded in $(document).ready();
$("input").on("invalid", function (e) {
    console.log("Invalidd");
    if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
        var msg = "";
        if (e.target.validity.valueMissing) {
            msg = "Esse campo é obrigatorio.";
        }
        if (e.target.validity.patternMismatch) {
            msg = "Formato incorreto.";
        }

        e.target.setCustomValidity(msg);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add the change event to your inputs as well as shown in the example at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation).

```
var inputs = $("form").find("input:not([type='submit'])"),
    validate = function (input) {
        var msg = "";

        if (!input.validity.valid) {
            if (input.validity.valueMissing) {
                msg = "Esse campo é obrigatorio.";
            }
            if (e.target.validity.patternMismatch) {
                msg = "Formato incorreto.";
            }
        }
        input.setCustomValidity(msg);
    };

inputs.on("change invalid", function (e) {
    validate(e.target);
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/Md93n/)